# How to save word vectors in spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have the following code. The goal is to get a vector representation of each word in the list. My intention is to use these word vectors for other application purpose like word clustering.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import en_vectors_web_lg
nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load() 

def vectorize(text):
    return nlp(text, disable=['parser', 'tagger', 'ner']).vector

category=['Dell','Python','Asus','Apple','C','perl','Java','iphone','nokia','LG','Lenovo']
for ntext in category:
    doc = nlp(ntext)

    vectors = normalize(np.stack(vectorize(t) for t in doc.text))
```

I realize i am doing something wrong in the code above. How to save the word vectors of each word in the list 'category'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen much documentation on using the `en_vectors_web_lg` model but I do know `en_core_web_lg` comes with vectors along with other functionality.

This is how you can vectorize each word/term in a list:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

category=['Dell','Python','Asus','Apple','C','perl','Java','iphone','nokia','LG','Lenovo']
doc = list(nlp.pipe(category, disable=['parser', 'tagger', 'ner']))
vectors = [term.vector for term in doc]
```

Each vector will look like below (300d):

```
[-0.94557    0.46092    0.43141   -0.52199    0.55764    0.18107
  0.45607    0.031909   0.097713   0.061064   0.061381  -0.37256
 -0.21712   -0.065784  -0.4061    -0.11485   -0.48388    1.5697
  ...
  0.03717   -0.6773    -0.19379    0.31747   -0.19495    0.37144  ]
```

You might also be interested in `vector_norm`: The L2 norm of the token’s vector (the square root of the sum of the values squared)

The vector norm for 'dell' would be 8.001050178690836

spaCy also has a built-in cosine similarity method `.similarity()` to compare vectors.